# Not able to render/plot Composite chart dc.js

Tags: d3.js, charts, composite, dc.js

This is a piece of a code in which I am able to get data correctly.But the issue is i am not able to plot chart.

Please refer this link to find chart image which I am getting

```
// This is where the composite chart code is starting.
CompositeChart: function (chartConfig, chartManager, meta) {

    var data = meta.data;
    var panelDetails = this.panelDetails(chartConfig.chartName);
    var chart = dc.compositeChart(panelDetails.id);
    var yAxisGroup = [];
    if (chartConfig.xDomainType == "Date" && !(data[0][meta.header[chartConfig.x]] instanceof Date)) {
        var dateFormater = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
        data.forEach(function (d, i) {
            d[meta.header[chartConfig.x]] = dateFormater.parse(d[meta.header[chartConfig.x]]);
        });
    }
    var xAxis = chartManager.cf.dimension(function (d) {
        var val = d[meta.header[chartConfig.x]];
        var result = (chartManager.dimValues[chartConfig.x]) ? chartManager.dimValues[chartConfig.x][val] : val;
        return result;
    });
    yAxisGroup = (chartConfig.y);
    var temp = yAxisGroup[0];
    var temp1 = yAxisGroup[1];

    var yDim1 = xAxis.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        var val = d[meta.header[temp]];
        var result = (chartManager.dimValues[temp]) ? chartManager.dimValues[temp][val] : val;
        return result;
    });
    var yDim2 = xAxis.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        var val = d[meta.header[temp1]];
        var result = (chartManager.dimValues[temp1]) ? chartManager.dimValues[temp1][val] : val;
        return result;
    });

    chart
        .width(panelDetails.width)
        .height(panelDetails.height)
        .margins({
            top: 35,
            right: 55,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 45
        })
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .shareColors(true)
        .compose([
            dc.lineChart(chart)
            .dimension(xAxis)
            .dashStyle([2, 2])
            .group(yDim1),
            dc.lineChart(chart)
            .dimension(xAxis)
            .dashStyle([5, 5])
            .group(yDim2)
        ])
        .brushOn(false);


    this.addXDomain(chartConfig, meta, chart, xAxis);
    chart.render();
    this.chartStore[chartConfig.chartName] = chart;
},
```

When I debug the data is fine. I am able to print it on console.But no luck on Chart
I am sharing data of X-Axis while grouping Y-Axis data. Any Solutions?

Note: Console is showing no error or exception.

Can any body help me find the parent chart? Guess that is the problem but I am not sure I need to pass the parent chat in compose function.

<kbd>[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lihkinrian/bRcK2/)</kbd>

Comment: I don't see any obvious bugs in your code.  It would help if your fiddle was standalone - meaning it had it's own local data and had all of the external references.  For example, here is a fiddle that hard codes some data and uses a cdn for d3/cf/dc: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/B2x9B/

Comment: The problem could be in many places... for example the panelDetails.id might not point to a html container on the page.... dc.compositeChart(panelDetails.id)

Comment: With little debug I found the solution for this particular problem that i was facing.The X Axis value was "NaN". This was the issue.I resolved it.  Thanks for the effort @DJ Martin

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure, but you might try putting your xaxis on the composite chart rather than each composed chart.

Here is a working chart that I've built:

```
        var actuals = dc.barChart(compositeChart)
                    .gap(65)
                    .group(group)
                    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                        return d.value.Actual;
                    });
            var budgets = dc.barChart(compositeChart)
                    .gap(65)
                    .group(group)
                    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                        return d.value.Budget;
                    });

            compositeChart
                    .width(1000)
                    .height(300)
                    .margins({top: 20, right: 45, bottom: 40, left: 50})
                    .dimension(monthDimension)
                    .group(group)
                    .elasticY(true)
                    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(timeExtent))
                    .xUnits(d3.time.months)
                    .round(d3.time.month.round)
                    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                    .compose([budgets, actuals])
                    .brushOn(true)
                    .title(function (d) {
                        return [
                            "Engagement: " + d.value.engagement,
                            "Amount:" + d.value.amount
                        ].join("\n");
                    })
                    .renderlet(function (chart) {
                        chart.selectAll("g._1").attr("transform", "translate(" + 20 + ", 0)");
                        chart.selectAll("g._0").attr("transform", "translate(" + 1 + ", 0)");
                    });
```

Note that the budget and actual charts do not define an x or xUnits method.  This is left to the composite chart.  Not sure that whether this is required or not, but I imagine you need to define x for the composite chart.